# Next JS router how to parse string into a valid url when pushing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, next.js

I have a string which look like this
`/dashboard/products/:id` and I want to use Next Js's router to push into that url and change the `:id` into a valid id.

This is my code

```
{products.map(product => <ProductCard onClick={() => router.push(PATHS.productDetail, { query: { id: 1 } })} />)}
```

My expectation is the user would be redirected to `/dashboard/products/1` but it goes to `/dashboard/products?id=1`

Is there any workaround for this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use that pattern for the URL

```
  router.push({
    pathname: '/dashboard/products/[id]',
    query: { id: 2 },
  })
```